# How to re-trigger hook without useEffect or a setState function?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using a custom hook that takes a URL as an argument and returns fetch data and its loading state. So, unlike most hooks, I do not have a function to set a new state when needed and this is causing all kinds of problems at this point in the project because I happen to need a way to re-trigger that custom hook everytime it receives new props values.

The issue is, as expected, the state of the component is being set upon components first render but as it receives new props it does not re-render/re-trigger.

This is how the custom hook looks like:

```
//useFetch.js

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function useFetch(url) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  async function fetchUrl() {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const json = await response.json();
    setData(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json)));
    setLoading(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUrl();
  }, []);

  return [data, loading];
}

export { useFetch };
```

and this is how I am using this hook:

```
//repos.js

import React from "react";
import { useFetch }  from "./fetchHook";


function Repos(props) {
  const [userRepos, reposLoading] = useFetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${props.users[props.count].login}/repos`);

  return reposLoading ? (
    <div className="App">
      stuff to render if it's still loading
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div
     stuff to render if it's loaded
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am passing it in to a string literal like ```${props.users[props.count].login}``` and those props does update everytime I send new props values but useFetch will not launch again after the first render.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add `url` to the dependencies array of `useFetch hook` this will make sure that the effect will rerun when the `url prop` changes

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("refetching url", url);
  fetchUrl();
}, [url]);
```

Comment: I did not know you could add a something to that array, this makes so much sense. Thank you! I now realise I should be doing some more document reading.

Comment: @ÖzençB. yea everything inside the dependencies array will cause a rerun of the effect, if you want the effect to act like `componentDidMount` provide an empty array, if you want to rerun the effect on every rerender dont provide the second `argument` at all